# ForEach Jmeter controller - How could I extract many variables and assign it to one user

Tags: jmeter

Hi I need to extract all documents assign to one user and write id down to csv document.

Generally it is a table with many numbers,

user:docID
user:docID2
etc..

I itterate the table with the regular expression extractor and write it down with post-processor beanshell. However, only one docID is assigned at a time.

I need to extract all of them at one time (about 30)

Comment: Please add the code you have written to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest avoid using Regular Expression Extractor component, and use Beanshell for everything. Something like:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;


String prevResponse = JMeterContextService.getContext().getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();

allMatches = new ArrayList();  // this was edited!
String regex = "yourRegexHere";
try {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.UNICODE_CASE).matcher(prevResponse);
    while (m.find())
        allMatches.add(m.group());
} catch (Exception e1) {
    // do someting
}
String myCSVfilePath = "home/username/Desktop/File.csv";

try {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(myCSVfilePath));
    for (String str : allMatches)
        pw.println("ACCT_ID:" + str);
    pw.close();
} catch (Exception e2) {
    // do someting
}
```

This should get all regex matches and write them down to your .csv file.